# How to use ORM while table already define in database?

Tags: node.js, orm, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using "sequelize" and "sqlite3"
But I don't know how to do even if the table s already exist in database.

i have seen the [document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) , but it seems that must define the schema everytime even if the table already exist ?

If the table already in database , how can I use it without define schema again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sequelize-auto** npm module for the same.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

I had the same situation before and used this npm module to generate the models, later can tweak or do some minor change if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Schema (model) definition only represents table in database and **does not create** table itself.

If table already exist you need to define schema for this table only when app starts.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if the table already exists, you need not use sync(); you can begin with User.create().